# Group items within into one div during an ng-repeat loop?

Tags: angularjs

So I have an XML feed of the weather, I've cut out the extra days (it goes up to day 3), and cut out the text within the elements:

```
<location type="station">
    <info></info>
    <values type="forecast_day0">
        <valid>
            <date>2015-11-11T06:00:00Z</date>
        </valid>
        <value type="temperature_2m_min_12h" unit="C">4</value>
    </values>

    <values type="forecast_day0">
        <valid></valid>
        <value type="precipitation_probability_12h" unit="percent">1</value>
        <value type="temperature_2m_max_12h" unit="C">13</value>
    </values>

    <values type="forecast_day1">
        <valid></valid>
        <value type="temperature_2m_min_12h" unit="C">3</value>
    </values>

    <values type="forecast_day1">
        <valid></valid>
        <value type="precipitation_probability_12h" unit="percent">5</value>
        <value type="temperature_2m_max_12h" unit="C">12</value>
    </values>

    <values type="forecast_day0">
        <valid>
            <start>2015-11-11T00:00:00Z</start>
            <end>2015-11-11T23:59:00Z</end>
        </valid>
        <text language="en">
            <title>Wednesday</title>
            <flashtext>Sunny periods.</flashtext>
        </text>
        <text language="it"></text>
        <text language="fr"></text>
        <text language="de"></text>
    </values>

    <values type="forecast_day0">
        <valid></valid>
        <symbol>10</symbol>
        <value type="insolation_2m_sum_1d" unit="h">5.9</value>
    </values>

    <values type="forecast_day0">
        <valid></valid>
        <symbol>10</symbol>
    </values>

    <values type="forecast_day0">
        <valid></valid>
        <symbol>10</symbol>
    </values>

    <values type="forecast_day1">
        <valid></valid>
        <text language="en"></text>
        <text language="it"></text>
        <text language="fr"></text>
        <text language="de"></text>
    </values>

    <values type="forecast_day1">
        <valid></valid>
        <symbol>2</symbol>
        <value type="insolation_2m_sum_1d" unit="h">4.5</value>
    </values>

    <values type="forecast_day1">
        <valid></valid>
        <symbol>2</symbol>
    </values>

    <values type="forecast_day1">
        <valid></valid>
        <symbol>10</symbol>
    </values>
</location>
```

This feed is downloaded and parsed using angular and angular-xml (that uses X2JS). I am having trouble figuring out the best way to loop the 'current day' -> as in to loop or group all  elements together.

My attempt was:

```
<div class="row" data-ng-repeat="forecast in location.values">
    <div class="col-md-2" data-ng-if="forecast.symbol != null">
        <div class="weather_symbol ws_{{forecast.symbol}}" style="width: 100%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" data-ng-if="forecast.__text != null">
        <div class="min_max">
            <span>min.</span>
            {{forecast.__text}}°C
            <br>
            <span>max.</span>
            {{forecast.__text}}°C
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="weather_desc">
            {{forecast.text}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```